# IE11 issue with flex-box screen doesnt fit properly Angular8

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am facing an issue with CSS issue in IE11, all other browsers it works correctly.
The issue is due to string length the screen doesnt fit in the browser properly.

I tried setting display:flex,flex: 1 1 auto, flex-wrap:wrap, white-space:pre-wrap to the parent div whose span has the long string.

Please help me to troubleshoot this.
I have also copied the IE11 generated HTML.

Note: The screenshot is cropped version.
[image]

HTML markup:

```
<div class="row pad1-0" _ngcontent-ean-c19="">
   <aside class="col-md-3 ng-star-inserted" id="sidebar" style="top: 0px;" _ngcontent-ean-c19="">
    <div class="toggle-side" _ngcontent-ean-c19="">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" _ngcontent-ean-c19=""></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="participant-menu popmenu" _ngcontent-ean-c19="">
      <li class="menu-item ia-language saved" data-goto="ia-language" _ngcontent-ean-c19="">
        Languages</li>
          </ul>
    </aside>

    <main class="col-md-9 ng-star-inserted" id="main" _ngcontent-ean-c19="">

    <section class="overview-options pad2-0 tright" _ngcontent-ean-c19="">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" _ngcontent-ean-c19="">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="window.print();" _ngcontent-ean-c19="">
          <i class="fa fa-print" _ngcontent-ean-c19=""></i> Print</button>
        <!--bindings={
       "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
       }--><button disabled="" class="btn btn-success btn-submit ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean- 
      c19="">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" _ngcontent-ean-c19=""></i> Submit</button>
      </div>
    </section>


    <app-languages-overview ng-reflect-model-errors="[object Object]" ng-reflect-has-edit-access="true" 
    ng-reflect-section="[object Object]" ng-reflect-validation-manager="[object Object]" ng-reflect-has- 
    fcdp-role="false" _ngcontent-ean-c19="" _nghost-ean-c21=""><section class="overview ia fields 
    language current" id="ia-language" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">

    <app-overview-card-header ng-reflect-title="Languages" ng-reflect-is-edit-hidden="true" ng-reflect- 
    row-version="AAAAAABxc2A=" _ngcontent-ean-c21="" _nghost-ean-c35=""><div class="partTitle flex-row" 
    _ngcontent-ean-c35="">
    <span class="secTitle" _ngcontent-ean-c35="">Languages</span>
    <div class="flex-row history-dropdown ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c35=""></div>
    <nav class="right" _ngcontent-ean-c35="">
      <a class="ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c35=""><i class="fa fa-history" _ngcontent-ean-c35=""> 
     </i></a>     
      <a class="ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c35=""><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt" _ngcontent-ean- 
    c35=""></i></a>
     <a class="ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c35=""><i class="fa fa-compress ng-star-inserted" 
    _ngcontent-ean-c35=""></i></a>
     </nav>
      </div>
      </app-overview-card-header>
     <div class="part language border-right ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">

     <div class="flex-row overviewContainer ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
      <div class="overview-field flex-row col-md-6 overviewItem" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
        <span title="What language do you use at home?" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Home 
     Language</span>
        <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">English&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="overview-field flex-row col-md-2 overviewItem" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
        <span title="Read" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Read</span>
        <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Yes&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="overview-field flex-row col-md-2 overviewItem" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
        <span title="Write" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Write</span>
        <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Yes&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="overview-field flex-row col-md-2 overviewItem" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
        <span title="Speak" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Speak</span>
        <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Yes&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
     <div class="flex-row overviewContainer ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
        <div class="overview-field flex-row col-md-6 caret overviewItem blank" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
          <span title="List any other languages you know" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Other 
       Language

          </span>
          <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="overview-field flex-row col-md-2 overviewItem blank" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
          <span title="Read" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Read</span>
          <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="overview-field flex-row col-md-2 overviewItem blank" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
          <span title="Write" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Write</span>
          <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="overview-field flex-row col-md-2 overviewItem blank" appHistoryData="" _ngcontent- 
      ean-c21="">
          <span title="Speak" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Speak</span>
          <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-row overviewContainer" _ngcontent-ean-c21=""></div>

    <div class="flex-row overviewContainer" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
      <div class="overview-field flex-row col-md-12 overviewItem blank" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">
        <span title="Notes" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">Notes</span>
        <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c21="">&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </section>
   </app-languages-overview>

     <app-ncp-overview style="overflow: hidden; display: flex; align-items: stretch;" ng-reflect-model- 
     errors="[object Object]" ng-reflect-has-edit-access="true" ng-reflect-section="[object Object]" ng- 
    reflect-validation-manager="[object Object]" ng-reflect-has-fcdp-role="false" _ngcontent-ean-c19="" 
    _nghost-ean-c33=""><section class="overview ia fields ncp current ng-star-inserted" id="ia-ncp" 
     _ngcontent-ean-c33="">


     <app-overview-card-header ng-reflect-title="Non-Custodial Parents" ng-reflect-is-edit-hidden="true" 
     ng-reflect-row-version="AAAAAABxggI=" _ngcontent-ean-c33="" _nghost-ean-c35=""><div 
    class="partTitle flex-row" _ngcontent-ean-c35="">
    <span class="secTitle" _ngcontent-ean-c35="">Non-Custodial Parents</span>
    <a class="ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c35=""><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt" _ngcontent-ean-c35=""> 
    </i></a>
     <a class="ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c35=""><i class="fa fa-compress ng-star-inserted" 
    _ngcontent-ean-c35=""></i><!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
    }--></a>
    </nav>
   </div>
   </app-overview-card-header>



   <div class="part ncp ng-star-inserted" style="flex:1 1 0px; overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex- 
     direction: row;" _ngcontent-ean-c33="">
     <div class="ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c33="">
          <div class="caretaker ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-ean-c33="">


              <div class="row" _ngcontent-ean-c33="">
                  <div class="overview-field col-md-4" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;" 
        _ngcontent-ean-c33="">
                      <span title="Relationship to Child(ren)" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean- 
        c33="">Relationship to Child(ren)</span>
                      <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c33="">Other Parent&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="overview-field col-md-8" style="flex:1 1 0px; overflow: hidden; display: 
      flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: stretch;" _ngcontent-ean-c33="">
                      <span title="Relationship to Child(ren) - Details" class="ovtitle" _ngcontent-ean- 
      c33="">Details</span>
                      <span class="ovval" _ngcontent-ean-c33="">fdsfadsfdsfdfdfdsfdsfsdfdfdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfasdfsdfasdfsfsdffdsfadsfdsfdfdfdsfdsfsdfdfdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfasdfsdfasdfsfsdffdsfadsfdsfdfdfdsfdsfsdfdfdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfasdfsdfasdfsfsdffdsfadsfdsfdfdfdsfdsfsdfdfdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfasdfsdfasdfsfsdffdsfadsfdsfdfdfdsfdsfsdfdfdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfasdfsdfasdfsfsdffdsfadsfdsfdfdfdsfdsfsdfdfdfdsfsdfsdfsdf&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
              </div>             

          </div>
      </div><div class="row" _ngcontent-ean-c33=""></div>
      <div class="row" _ngcontent-ean-c33=""></div>
     </div>

    </section>
   </app-ncp-overview>

  </main>
   </div>
```

Comment: Yes I know but what to do business users wont listen to this

Comment: IE11 only has partial support with Flexbox properties so there's only so much you can accommodate. You provided your HTML but didnt show any of your CSS. Are you familiar with `display: -ms-flexbox;` [you can read more about that here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mixins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue, the word-break: break-word; was causing the issue in IE11,
i changed it to word-break: break-all; and it started working..spent 3 hrs  on this :)